# Adding mouse listener stops browser scroll

Tags: actionscript, flash, actionscript-2

After adding a mouseListener via Mouse.addListener to my flash movie the mouse wheel event is not bubbling to the browser when the mouse cursor is placed over the flash movie.

People all over google are complaining that in AS3 the event is bubbling and it is hard to stop it but in AS2 I wasn't able to find a solution to get the behaviour just as it is in AS3. Any ideas guys?

Some code:

```
var mouseListener:Object = new Object();
mouseListener.onMouseMove = function() {    
    trace("mouseMove");
}
mouseListener.onMouseDown = function() {
    trace("mouseDown"); 
}
mouseListener.onMouseUp = function() {
    trace("mouseUp");
}
Mouse.addListener(mouseListener);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of googling I gave up and got rid of the MouseListener alltogether. That was actually quite straightforward.